# How to update a cardview button based on a volley response

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view adapter that display a list of cars (cardviews) and in the card view I have a button that when the user clicks 
send some data to the server and returns a response of "true" or false;

When the user clicks on the button, I hide the button and show a progress bar showing the user that something is happening, 
the button calls a different function that has a volley call and the response, then I have another functoin that validates the response.

What I'm trying to do is to hide the progress bar of that specific card view when i get the response and show a message with the result, I'm passing the position of the cardview
but I'm not able to change the specific progress bar.

I have tried to find the progressbar by doing.

Progressbar progres = findviewbyid(R.id.myprogressbar);

But it finds the progress bar of the last cardview not the one that it was click.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CarViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final CartItem currentItem = _carList.get(position);

    String name = currentItem.getCarName();
    String date = currentItem.getCarDate();



    String instructions = currentItem.getInstructions();
    String description = currentItem.getInstructions2();
    String carKey = currentItem.getKey();


    holder.name.setText(name);
    holder.date.setText("Date: " + date);
    holder.instructions.setText(instructions);
    holder.description.setText(description);
    holder.carKey.setText(carKey);

    holder.car_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.car_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            carProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.car_button.setText("Thank you!");
            holder.car_date.setText("");
            holder.car_button.setClickable(false);
            carDate(currentItem.getCarName(), currentItem.getKey(), position);
        }
    });
} 


public void carDate(String name, String key, final int position) {
    _Key = key;
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Thank you! -  " + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    String url = "url=key"+key;

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "KEY RESPONSE: " + response + " : " + position);
            try {
                result = response.getString("result");
                validateResponse(result, position);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    carQueue.add(request);
}
```

Here is where I'm trying to hide the progress bar and show the message with the response;

```
public void validateResponse(String result, int position) {
    CarItem carItem = _carList.get(position);

    if (result.equals("true")) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "--> " + result + " <---", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "--> " + result + " <---", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind `RecyclerView` is that each row should represent the current state of the underlying object.

I usually subclass my object to add some values related to the view state. Then I call `notifyItemChanged(position: Int)` each time the state change. Here an example code:

```
//The original object
open class MObject(val name: String)
//Add the field isCalling to the underlying object
class MWrapper(name: String, var isCalling: Boolean = false): MObject(name)
```

MAdapter

```
class MAdapter(private val items: List<MWrapper>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    ...

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items[position]
        with(holder){
            tv.text = if (item.isCalling) "I'm calling" else item.name

            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                //Set isCalling to true
                onCallStateChange(item, position)
                //Simulate a 5 sec long network call
                Handler().postDelayed({ onCallStateChange(item, position, false) }, 5000L)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun onCallStateChange(
        item: MWrapper, 
        position: Int, 
        isCalling: Boolean = true
    ){
        item.isCalling = isCalling
        notifyItemChanged(position)
    }

}
```